# The document has moved here. in Perl

Tags: perl

I am getting: "The document has moved here." ERROR page after redirecting . It's a 302 error message. Can anybody please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: 302 isn't an error. It's an HTTP status code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where are you getting an error? Provide details so that people can help you. (Also, 302 isn't an error, its a notification something has moved.)

Comment: I am trying to seelct language. On seleting of radio button I am redirecting the page to home page with new language translations. This is the line for redirection.=> "print $cgi->redirect(-cookie=>$cookie,-Location=>"http://localhost/testmyapp/home.pl");"

Comment: Its not error but need to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A redirect tells the client to issue a new request to find the resource

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.yoursite.tld/new/location
```

Your client code must read the `Location:` header and then issue a second request to wherever the provided URL points, in order to fetch the real content.

Answer (score -1):

As I said, it's not an error, it's an HTTP status code. There is no problem to resolve except your lack of understanding of what your code does. See the [CGI module documentation](http://p3rl.org/CGI), the [redirect method](http://p3rl.org/CGI#GENERATING_A_REDIRECTION_HEADER).

**You** are redirecting, you are issuing the 302 redirect.

Comment: Then what can we do?  After redirecting and clicing on "here" link, it should show me page in the selected language but its not showing.

Comment: @bHUSHAN ensure that the Location of your redirect actually exists. You need to read the FAQ about asking questions, you've not given enough info and don't seem to understand the very basics of what you're doing. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I have googled then only I have posted here. Location exists at "here". I am developer and I can crosscheck and  did that atleast before posting here.

Comment: `I am developer and I can crosscheck and did that atleast before posting here.` yet you don't know the different between a HTTP response and an error? `I have googled then only I have posted here.` If you googled based on your description here I'm not surprised you didn't find anything useful.

Comment: I am asking for the solution for proper redirection rather than getting  HTTP RESPONSE and need working functionality.

Comment: @bHUSHAN I already linked to the CGI documentation and suggested a debugging course of action. I can't make you do it.